# Select at least one checkbox, PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

I am trying to set up a form with validation.  Setting up checkboxes that require the user to select at least one box is becoming quite a pain. I have tried most solutions that seemed promising from this and other forums, but to no avail.

So we have two different checkboxes that are going to different emails depending on which the user chooses.  Right now, if you submit this form without selecting a checkbox, the form just refreshes, you get no error message.  So I guess technically it's validating but the user is not getting the error message?

Code is a little messy, this is a test form we're setting up to experiment and see if we can make it functional before we build the real thing for a client.

Very novice with PHP and Javascript, by the way. Thanks in advance!

Here's the PHP code...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}


if(trim($_POST['checkbox']) == '') {
$agree = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'checkbox');
$checked = '';

if( empty($agree) )
$errors['checkbox'] = true;
else{
$checked = 'checkbox';
}
}
//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError) && $_POST['Charlotte']) {
    $emailTo = 'Charlotte@email.com'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}



//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError) && $_POST['Mary']) {
    $emailTo = 'Mary@email.com'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n       $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;
}

}

?>
```

Here's the Javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
var validator = $("#contactform").validate({
    rules: {
        contactname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        checkbox: {
            required: true,
        },
        subject: {

            minlength: 2
        },
        message: {

            minlength: 10
        }

    },
    messages: {
        contactname: {
            required: "Please enter your name",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Your name needs to be at least {0} characters")
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter a valid email address",
            minlength: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        checkbox: {
            required: "Please select at least one location"
        },
        subject: {
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        },
        message: {
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        }
    },
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("checked");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Here's the form in HTML...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="contactWrapper" role="form">
  <h1 role="heading">Send a message</h1>
  <?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>
  <p class="error">Please check if you've filled all the fields with valid information and try again. Thank you.</p>
    <?php } ?>
<?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
  <div class="success">
  <p><strong>Email Successfully Sent!</strong></p>
  <p>Thank you for contacting us <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong>! Your email was successfully sent and we'll be in touch with you soon.</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
  <div class="stage clear">
    <label for="name">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name:<em>*</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
  </div>
  <div class="stage clear">
    <label for="email">Email:<em>*</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" role="input" aria-required="true" />
  </div>
  <div class="stage clear">
  <ul>
  <p>Please select a box*</p>
  <li><input type='checkbox' name='Charlotte' value='1' id='checkbox' /><label for="Charlotte">Charlotte</label></li>
  <li><input type='checkbox' name='Mary' value='2' id='checkbox' /><label for="Mary">Mary</label></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="stage clear">
    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
  </div>
  <div class="stage clear">
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea rows="8" name="message" id="message" class="required" role="textbox" aria-required="true"></textarea>
  </div>
  <p class="requiredNote"><em>*</em>Denotes a required field.</p>
  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" id="submitButton" title="Click here to submit your message!" />
</form>


</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do not you use a checkbox array like name="location[]"? Then in php, you can check if the checkbox is isset, if not isset i.e. not present in $_POST, return array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(trim($_POST['Charlotte']) != 1 and trim($_POST['Mary']) != 2){
$hasError = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
function Validate()
{
if (document.getElementById("check").checked == false )

                {
                    alert("please select one checkbox");
                            return false;
                }
}

</script>

<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="c[]" id="check">
<-----submit the code----->
 <input name="one" onclick="Validate()" value="send" type="submit">
```